# Searching for patterns and only getting the patterns as output (R)?

Tags: r, string, search, vector

I'm pretty new to R and I would appreciate any answer :)

I want to search for a pattern within elements of a vector and **only return that pattern**.

let's say my vector is

```
("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99")
```

I want the output to be of the pattern `[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]. And **only the first occurrence of it**.

The vector should then be

```
("7BC", "A56", "M33")

grep("[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]", nameofvector)
```

returns the whole entry and I don't know how to return only the found pattern.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How `"7BC"` is in expected output?

Comment: I've got a character vector with 3 elements.

The function should look for the pattern [0-9][A-Z][A-Z] and return those parts of those elements that are according to the pattern.

Thank you :)

Comment: `7BC` has the form number-character-character whereas other two has character-number-number. What is that you want as final output? Also the pattern you have used in `grep` is different than what you have written 2 lines above it.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with `grep` in R. (It would probably in Linux, but not in R). Here's how to do it with `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
x <- c("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99")
out <-stri_extract_first(x, regex="[A-Z][0-9][0-9]")
out[!is.na(out)]
#[1] "A56" "M33"
```

By the way, your regex pattern will not match "7BC". You will have to change your regex.

Answer (score 0):

The `stringr` package has a lot of convenient wrappers for regex stuff in R. Try:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(c('7AB-2CC-120', '111-3ZC'), '[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]')
```

---

```
[1] "7AB" "3ZC"
```

Answer (score 0):

At one point you ask for "[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]" and another point for "[A-Z][0-9][0-9]", so people are have difficulty understanding what you do want. If you just want the first three letters of the character vector items than it would be:

```
substr( c("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99"), 1,3)
```

If you want any item that starts with "[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]" then add an an up-caret, "^", to the pattern given to `grepl` for selection of the desired match and then use `substr`:

```
 vec <- c("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99")
 substr( vec[grepl( "^[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]", vec)], 1,3)
 # "7BC"   .... and the solution for the alternate is obvious.
```

And if you want either pattern then use the regex-OR symbol which is `"|"`:

```
 vec <- c("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99")
 substr( vec[grepl( "^[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]|^[A-Z][0-9][0-9]", vec)], 1,3)
#[1] "7BC" "A56" "M33"
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, that was a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
string<-c("7BC-137", "A56_asdf", "M33_T99")
gsub('(_|-).*','',string)
[1] "7BC" "A56" "M33"
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer.